# Passing an argument to the T-SQL Nodes method (XML CROSS APPLY)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am getting the error below when I use this syntax. I want to be able to pass the argument to the nodes function:-

```
CROSS APPLY XML_TPYE_COLUMN.nodes(@p_Xpath) AS Tab(Col)
```

Error:

```
The argument 1 of the XML data type method "nodes" must be a string literal.
```

Can someone tell me how do i do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do this via dynamic sql since the parameter for nodes must be a string literal. This is similar to what you do when you do `sp_executesql`.

In other words, you need to construct your entire sql statement as nvarchar(max) and pass it to sp_executesql:

```
DECLARE @statement nvarchar(max)= N'select  ... CROSS APPLY col.nodes('+@p_Xpath+') AS Tab(Col)'

execute sp_executesql N@statement
```