# sql:variable to define xpath in MS-SQL nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery, xquery-sql

I have scanned a few examples and commentaries from different blogs, and although I have seen a lot of examples using sql:variable to select certain nodes/attributes, I am not sure something as simple as a node selection can be replaced with a SQL variable.  For example, if I have the following:

```
declare @NodeStartPoint    varchar(255) = '/root/parent/child'
```

and later, I might use the cross apply something like:

```
cross apply MyXml.nodes(@NodeStartPoint)
```

obviously the above cross apply nodes selection doesn't work.  I also tried:

```
cross apply MyXml.nodes('sql:variable(@NodeStartPoint)')
```

and probably a few other strange combinations too!

The idea is so that I can pass in the node selection from a param etc..

I have started looking through http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mrys/ and also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186960%28SQL.90%29.aspx but so far, I cannot find any example of what I am trying to achieve, which makes me think I am barking up the wrong tree! :)

Any ideas gratefully received !!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, sort of answering my own question given the type of responses I have seen to similar question around the internet.. this one is very similar: [Passing an argument to the T-SQL Nodes method (XML CROSS APPLY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946224/passing-an-argument-to-the-t-sql-nodes-method-xml-cross-apply)

So, I am guessing it can't be done using a variable replacement in the nodes() statement..

Comment: Nope, `sql_variable` can't be used to replace the xQuery expression. The expression has to be a string literal and it is used when SQL Server builds the query plan so there is no way to allow a "runtime" change of the expression. Using [dynamic SQL an option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14812275/569436).

Comment: Thanks yet again @Mikael !! after trawling through lots of articles, it certainly looks like that.. I can understand given what the SQL engine has to do, so for now I will either try the dynamic sql approach, or not use params for the expression (as in they will not be changing that much anyway).  I will mark this answer correct just to show up if other searching, however you should really get the credit :)

Comment: If you have a known depth of nodes you could use `local-name()` to check against `sql:variable`. If for instance you have three level xpath expression `/a/b/c` then you could do it without dynamic SQL if you used three parameters and checked each level with `local-name() = sql:variable("Param1")` etc.

Comment: You could use something like this as a starting point: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3069). Just modify the expression to use the checks where you need to have alternative paths.

Comment: Hey thanks @MikaelEriksson !! I have actually managed (with your examples) to get it to work.. which is great.. thanks a lot for that!